# How can I make a big message of countdown? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I want to make big messages of countdown.I found one form with the message dialog box but its smaller than i want. 
This is the code that i have proved but its very small,i need a big message of countdown.

```
msgbox('3');
pause(1)
msgbox('2');
pause(1)
msgbox('1');
pause(1)
msbox('smile');
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of redundant code in your example. This is a bit cleaner:

```
% Initialize our figure
fh = figure( ...
    'MenuBar', 'none', ...     % Get rid of unnecessary UI elements
    'DockControls', 'off', ... % Get rid of unnecessary UI elements
    'ToolBar', 'none', ...     % Get rid of unnecessary UI elements
    'Units', 'Pixels', ...     % Makes it a bit easier to set position
    'Position', [500 300 500 500] ... % Position, pixels [x, y, width, height]
    );

% Initialize our text box
textbox = uicontrol( ...
    'Parent', fh, ...              % Put it in our figure window
    'Style', 'text', ...           % We want a text box
    'Units', 'Normalized', ...     % Scale the box relative to figure window
    'Position', [0, 0, 1, 1], ...  % Scale the box relative to figure window
    'FontUnits', 'Normalized', ... % Scale font relative to text box
    'FontSize', 0.8 ...            % Scale font relative to text box
    );

startnum = 10; % Our starting number
while startnum >= 0
    set(textbox, 'String', startnum); % Update text box string
    pause(1)                          % Wait 1 second
    startnum = startnum - 1;          % Subtract one from our counter
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution.

```
h = msgbox(' 3');
set(h, 'position', [500 300 100 100]); %makes box bigger
ah = get( h, 'CurrentAxes' );
ch = get( ah, 'Children' );
set( ch, 'FontSize', 70 ); %makes text bigger
pause(1)
h = msgbox(' 2');
set(h, 'position', [500 300 100 100]); %makes box bigger
ah = get( h, 'CurrentAxes' );
ch = get( ah, 'Children' );
set( ch, 'FontSize', 70 ); %makes text bigger
pause(1)
h = msgbox(' 1');
set(h, 'position', [500 300 100 100]); %makes box bigger
ah = get( h, 'CurrentAxes' );
ch = get( ah, 'Children' );
set( ch, 'FontSize', 70 ); %makes text bigger
pause(1)
```